# Bioacoustic Data

Tags: data-request, biology

I'm looking for bat bioacoustic data. Preferably the data would cover a large geographic scope (i.e., not constrained to a single country/continent). Species data would be very useful, but most important are call counts.

Comment: What do you mean with "bioacoustic"? Please clarify and also  please indicate in the question that you're looking for data on bats.

Comment: Google Dr. Laura Kloepper. She could guide you in the right direction. But like @Grimaldi expressed, make sure to have more specific questions in mind.